# Retrofit post request with string on body

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, request, retrofit

I want to receive a token for  server after the anonymous authentication with firebase. Initially, my goal is to receive the token associated with a particular user's firebase and send this token to  post request with retrofit and received JSON file with the information of the user (nickname, playerId, token refresh and token access). 
My problem is in `callbackAnonymous.enqueue`, the computer not execute this call.

SplashScreenActivity

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var idToken : String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        getTokenId()
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user == null) {
            auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("error: ", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getTokenId(){
        val mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        mUser!!.getIdToken(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    idToken = task.result!!.token.toString()
                    sendTo()
                } else {

                }
            }
    }

    fun sendto(){
        val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils.getRetrofitInstance()
        val endpoint = retrofitClient.create(Endpoint::class.java)
        val callbackAnonymous = endpoint.anonymousAuthentication(idToken)

        callbackAnonymous.enqueue(object : Callback<Authentication> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Authentication>?, response: Response<Authentication>?) {
                response?.code()?.let {
                    var code = it
                    if (code == 409){
                        Log.e("User exists", "User exists")
                    }
                    if (code == 401){
                        Log.e("Unauthorized", "Invalid token")
                    }
                    if(code == 200) {
                        response?.body()?.let {
                            val note: Authentication = it
                            var accessToken = note.session?.access_token.toString()
                            var refreshToken = note.session?.refresh_token.toString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Authentication?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@SplashScreenActivity)
                builder.setTitle("Error")
                builder.setMessage("Servidor erros. Please try again later.")
                builder.create().show()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Endpoint

```
interface Endpoint {
    @POST("player/auth/anonymous/firebase")
    fun anonymousAuthentication(@Body body: String?): Call<Authentication>
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring the case where this is false: `if (task.isSuccessful) {`, which means you'll never know if something went wrong in that task. You'll want to look at `task.getException()` if the task is no successful.

Comment: Try to use logging-interceptor for debugging check this for implementation https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/README.md Hope this helpf